# SQL Server calculating duration between 2 times (hh:mm format)

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I am trying to calculate two different times (24 hour format) on SQL server.

I keep getting an error message when I want to substract the end time from the start time:

> The data types nvarchar and nvarchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

[image: This is how my data looks like in SQL server table]

Comment: you should cast those varchar times as datetime before subtracting. Something like: CAST(time2 as datetime) - CAST(time1 as datetime)

Comment: @Javier I have tried and I get this error  from sql server **The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

Comment: Try this: SELECT TimeDiff_InMinutes = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(DATETIME,sTime), CONVERT(DATETIME,eTime)) FROM TABLE_NAME

Comment: "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." Yes, because 24:00 is not a real time... Perhaps you want to replace those with '00:00' first. And also you would want to add a day to endtime when it is less than starttime presumably...

Comment: good catch @ZLK

Comment: @ZLK Thank you so much. it works. Now I got a new problem, the output shows **1899-12-31 08:50:00.000**. How can I convert this data into 8.50 hours instead of **1899-12-31 08:50:00.000**? I want my duration to be in digit with decimal?

Comment: try casting the difference like this: cast(timediff as float) * 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. (one more thing don't save the end of time 24:00 it's must be saved 23:59 because it's consider out of range value.)

```
Select CONVERT(TIME, (CONVERT(DATETIME,EndTime) - CONVERT(DATETIME,StartTime))) ,* from @tblName
```

For Example

```
Declare @tbl Table(
ArrangeId INT ,
BeginDate   NVARCHAR(50),
EndDate   NVARCHAR(50),
DeptId INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'7:20','22:30',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'7:00','23:00',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(2,'7:00','23:59',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(4,'5:00','22:30',NULL)


Select CONVERT(TIME, (CONVERT(DATETIME,EndDate) - CONVERT(DATETIME,BeginDate))) As RemainingTime,* from @tbl
```

Comment: Thanks. quick question. Can DATEDIFF and DATEADD achieve the same result as above?